# Monero blockchain fetch blocks by date

Tags: rpc, api

I'd like to use the Monero API. Is there a REST API method which can fetch Monero blocks by specific date?

Thanks
Sajudeen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

However, you can get blocks by height, and height maps fairly well to date. There are on average two minutes per block since height 1009827, and one minute per block before that. It's then a simple conversion.

To get blocks by height, use the [getblockheadersrange](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_headers_range), which has start_height and end_height parameters.

Example:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block_headers_range","params":{"start_height":1545999,"end_height":1546000}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```